# Mac app similar to Scribble feature in iPadOS

Tags: software-recommendation, accessibility, handwriting

I want to use a graphic tablet (for example from Wacom) to navigate through my Mac as alternative to a mouse or trackpad. It would be amazing if I could also use it to replace my keyboard for writing. iPadOS has recently introduced its [Scribble feature](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/enter-text-with-scribble-ipad355ab2a7/ipados) which allows the user to write into a textfield by hand using their Apple Pencil and the OS would transcribe the handwriting into typed text.
The way I'd hope for this to work is comparable to the integrated dictation feature, which I can use in any text field across the whole OS, including browser text fields and so on.

Is there something similar for the Mac?

#### Note:

I'm NOT talking about note taking apps, or apps that can take a handwritten document and transform it into a typed document. Instead, what I'm looking for should work anywhere and transform my handwriting into typed text *on the fly*.

#### Background:

The reason I'm considering this is that I'm suffering from tendovaginitis and have a really hard time typing...If you know any other approach that could help me, that'd be out of scope for this question, but I'd appreciate any tips via my [Twitter](https://twitter.com/linusgeffarth).

Comment: Sorry, there *was* a handwriting framework in macOS, but they removed it in Catalina. You'll have to use a third-party app. There is one called Inklet.

Comment: Yeah I've realized that they removed it not too long ago, unfortunately... Inklet doesn't seem to turn handwriting into typed text though, does it? Maybe I've just missed that part.